# How come this geometry point does not intersect with the polygon?

Tags: sql-server-2008, spatial, sqlgeography

How come this geometry point does not intersect with the polygon? I know for a fact that the point exists in the given polygon. Any reason why it returns 0?

```
DECLARE @point geometry 
DECLARE @poly geometry

SET @point = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (-79.393967 43.640056)', 4326)

DECLARE @minY varchar(20) = N'-79.37776573850101'
DECLARE @maxY varchar(20) = N'-79.41055306149906'
DECLARE @minX varchar(20) = N'43.63590433545648'
DECLARE @maxX varchar(20) = N'43.64460037532088'

DECLARE @boundingRect varchar(250)
SET @boundingRect = 'POLYGON((' + @minX + ' '  + @minY + ', ' + 
                                                   @maxX + ' ' + @minY + ', ' + 
                                                   @maxX + ' ' + @maxY + ', ' + 
                                                   @minX + ' ' + @maxY + ', ' + 
                                                   @minX + ' ' + @minY + '))'

SET @poly = geometry::STGeomFromText(@boundingRect, 4326)

SELECT @point.STIntersects(@poly)
```

Comment: Did you try to intersect a point with the polygon, which lies on one of the edges? Iam interested in the result.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with this SQL notation, so I may be way off base, but I see that your X values seem to be associated with latitude 43N, and Y with longitude 79W. However, your POINT entries might be reversed?

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought: When does a point intersect with a polygon? If it lies INSIDE the polygon? No. Only if it lies directly on one of the edges of the polygon, right?
Try this: Intersect a point with the polygon, which is lying directly on one of the edges of the polygon. If it returns else then 0 you have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The point should be declared as:

```
SET @point = geometry::STGeomFromText('POINT (43.640056 -79.393967)', 4326)
```

Then the Intersect shows the result you're expecting: 1